# Adding custom data attribute to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add `data` attribute to the DOM elements with jQuery but only when the `$(window).width` is greater that 800px. So right now I have this code and it's not working.

Note: Chrome Developer Tools doesn't report any issues in the code.

Code:

```
<div id="wallpaper"></div>
<div id="wallpaper-right"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var width = $(window).width(),
    wallpapers = $("#wallpaper, #wallpaper-right"),
    container = $(".container");

if ( width > 800) {
    wallpapers.data("stellar-ratio") === 0.1;
    container.data("stellar-ratio") === 1;
}
```

Desired result in HTML after adding the `data` attributes:

```
<div id="wallpaper" data-stellar-ratio="0.1"></div>
<div id="wallpaper-right" data-stellar-ratio="0.1"></div>
<div class="container" data-stellar-ratio="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this

```
   if ( width > 800) {
        wallpapers.attr({"data-stellar-ratio":"0.1"});
        container.attr({"data-stellar-ratio":"1"});
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To set a value to a `data` attribute, you should pass it as the 2nd parameter in `.data()` method :

```
wallpapers.data("stellar-ratio", 0.1);
container.data("stellar-ratio", 1);
```

What you have written here is comparing values and type between `data-stellar-ratio` and 0.1 or 1.

Here's the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for `.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

to set a data value, you need to pass it as the second parameter of the method

```
var width = $(window).width(),
    wallpapers = $("#wallpaper, #wallpaper-right"),
    container = $(".container");

if ( width > 800) {
    wallpapers.data("stellar-ratio",0.1);
    container.data("stellar-ratio",1);
}
```